# Gson Streaming API : Not able to read all iterations of JsonObject

Tags: java, json, parsing, stream, gson

I'm using GSON streaming api for parsing one of the huge data response in the JSON, where the JSON is like inside an Array object we have list of all objects and each objects has some properties. Now the problem is that, when i'm trying to parse this response through my code, it works perfectly fine for the first object set and perfectly iterates through each property inside it, but as it moves to the second object, it fails at first line throwing the following error.

> Expected name but was BEGIN_OBJECT at Line // line number pointing to that of BeginObject for 2nd object in the JSON

This is my JSON structure i'm using to parse:

```
{
"Report_Entry": [
    {
       "key1": "value",
       "key2": "value",
       "key3": "value",
       "key4": "value",
       "key5": "value"
    },
    {
       "key1": "value",
       "key2": "value",
       "key3": "value",
       "key4": "value",
       "key5": "value"
    }
]}
```

This is the code which i'm using for parsing, how we can achieve the desired output?

```
        try {
        HCMCycleTimePerBp hcmCycleTimePerBp = new HCMCycleTimePerBp();

        poJSONReaderObj.beginObject();
        while (poJSONReaderObj.hasNext()) {
            
            String name = poJSONReaderObj.nextName();
            if (name.equals("Report_Entry")) {
                poJSONReaderObj.beginArray();
                while (poJSONReaderObj.hasNext()) {
                    
                    JsonToken nextToken2 = poJSONReaderObj.peek();
                    if (JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT.equals(nextToken2)) {
                        poJSONReaderObj.beginObject();
                    } else if (JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(nextToken2)) {
                        poJSONReaderObj.endObject();
                    } else {
                        String nextString = "";
                        if (JsonToken.STRING.equals(nextToken2)) {
                            nextString = poJSONReaderObj.nextString();
                        } else if (JsonToken.NAME.equals(nextToken2)) {
                            nextString = poJSONReaderObj.nextName();
                        }

                        switch (nextString) {
                        case "key1":
                            hcmCycleTimePerBp.setKey1(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key2":
                            hcmCycleTimePerBp.setKey2(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key3":
                            hcmCycleTimePerBp.setKey3(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key4":
                            hcmCycleTimePerBp.setKey4(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                        case "key5":
                            hcmCycleTimePerBp.setKey5(poJSONReaderObj.nextString());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                
                poJSONReaderObj.endObject();

                System.out.println(
                        "Value of Map is : " + new Gson().toJson(hcmCycleTimePerBp) + "counter  : " + counter);
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Counter : " + counter);
            }
        }
        JsonToken nextToken = poJSONReaderObj.peek();
        if (JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(nextToken)) {
            poJSONReaderObj.endObject();
        } else if (JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(nextToken)) {
            poJSONReaderObj.endArray();
        }
    } catch (
        IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exactly know the JSON structure then you can get rid of the `peek()` and `JsonToken....equals(...)` calls and instead use:

```java
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.beginObject();

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        String value = reader.nextString();

        ...
    }

    reader.endObject();
}
reader.endArray();
```

This might not directly solve your problem, but it makes it easier to spot where the issue is. Your current code would for example in some cases not consume values because not all of your `if` and `switch` statements have `else` or `default`, so in case of unexpected JSON data your code would call `JsonReader` methods at unrelated places causing difficult to track down errors.